# Tabulate Area crashes Python and ArcGIS

Tags: python, raster, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

I have a script that runs `Tabulate Area` on a single feature class multiple times with different rasters.  In total `Tabulate Area` runs 5 times.  2 of the input rasters are provided as arguments to the script and `Tabulate Area` works as expected.  The other 3 rasters are results of raster functions (i.e. `Reclassify, SetNull, EucDistance, etc.`).

Every time I run the script, Python crashes when trying to run `Tabulate Area` on one of those preprocessed rasters.  It happens on a different raster every time, seemingly randomly.  There is no error message, Python simply crashes.  When I hit `Get Details` in the generic Windows error dialog, it seems like there is a different Fault Module every time as well.

When I try to run `Tabulate Area` manually in ArcCatalog, ArcCatalog crashes and asks if I want to send a report to ESRI.  Again, no error message.

**UPDATE:**

Here is some of the code involved:

```
def GetBuffer(inRaster, lcClass, bufDist, ringBuffer=True):

    setnull = SetNull(inRaster, 1, "Value <> " + str(lcClass))

    dist = EucDistance(setnull, bufDist)

    buf = Reclassify(dist, "Value", RemapRange([[0, 100, 1], ["NODATA", 0]]))

    if ringBuffer:

        reclass = Reclassify(setnull, "Value", RemapValue([[0, 0], [1, 1], ["NODATA", 0]]))

        ring = arcpy.gp.Minus_sa(buf, reclass)

        return ring

    else: return buf

def SubtractRaster(inRaster1, inRaster2):

    sub = arcpy.gp.Minus_sa(inRaster1, inRaster2)

    setnull = SetNull(sub, 1, "Value <> 1")

    return setnull

lcRaster = arcpy.Raster(landcover)

treecanopy = GetBuffer(lcRaster, TreeCanopyClass, TreeCanopyBuffer, False)

parkinglots = SubtractRaster(GetBuffer(lcRaster, ParkingLotClass, ParkingLotBuffer), treecanopy)

buildings = SubtractRaster(GetBuffer(lcRaster, BuildingClass, BuildingBuffer), treecanopy)

impervious = SubtractRaster(GetBuffer(lcRaster, ImperviousClass, ImperviousBuffer), treecanopy)

...

TabulateArea(fc, "GID", parkinglots, "Value", plTabArea , 1)

TabulateArea(fc, "GID", buildings, "Value", buildTabArea , 1)

TabulateArea(fc, "GID", impervious, "Value", impTabArea , 1)
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I installed ArcGIS 10.1 Service Pack 1 after seeing bugs related to `Tabulate Area` in 10.1.  When I first ran the script with SP1, it worked.  When I ran it again later, I had the same issue where Python simply crashed without providing an error message.

Comment: Could you post your script?

Comment: @Aaron - I've added some of the code in an update to the post.

Comment: I would put some arcpy.GetMessage... lines in your code to provide some feedback so you at least know where it is failing of no errors are being reported.

Comment: @DanPatterson - I actually had print statements in there, but I took them out for the code sample so it wouldn't be as cluttered.  That's how I know it is failing at the one of the 3 `TabulateArea` calls (and a different one of the 3 each time).

Comment: Then could you provide the results of the print statements Brian so the line of failure can be examined?

Comment: @DanPatterson - There is no specific error.  Python.exe simply crashes and must be restarted (I am notified via a standard Windows dialog).  The `print` statement tells me that everything has been processed up to one of the 3 `Tabulate Area` calls.  For instance, it might say `"Impervious Ring Buffer created"` or `"Parking Lots Tabulate Area Complete"` or `"Buildings Tabulate Area Complete"`.  By the way, I am running this in IDLE and not via and ArcGIS Script Tool.

Comment: Have you tried leaving off the cell size option and doing the default?

Comment: @gm70560 - I tried the no cell size option as well with no luck.  I also tried to rasterize my zone data first and that also didn't help.

Comment: @Brian, Your input rasters are in a projected coordinate system (not geographic)?

Comment: @artwork21 - input rasters are projected and match the coordinate system of the zone feature class.

Answer (score 1):

You are running 10.1; have you installed any service packs?  There is a list of bugs found for ["tabulate area crashes"](http://search.esri.com/results/index.cfm?do=support.index&start=0&as_q=&site=&dr=0&startDate=&REQUIREDFIELDS=%28search-category%3Abugs%2Fnimbus%29&num=10&FILTER=p&SEARCHVIEW=all&FILTERID=2&getfields=%2a&endDate=&q=tabulate+area+crashes)  from esri's support page.  Check to see if any apply to you, or check other searches about the tool.

Comment: I hunted for bugs and did not find any directly related to this, but apparently I wasn't looking in the right place.  I installed ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 and it worked just fine.  Next is to play around with the new 64bit background processing capabilities.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, false alarm.  It worked the first time I ran it and then upon more testing, I'm getting the same issue again even with SP1.

Comment: Do you save the rasters subtraction, getBuffer, etc? And do they have attribute tables? [check this](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000wq000000.htm)

Comment: I don't save the intermediate rasters, but I do save the result of the `SubtractRaster` calls.  According to the link you provided, which I have seen before, that attribute table is only needed for the zone data, which in this case is vector.  All my rasters do have an attribute table as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed it by (re)building the attribute table just before tabulating the area in my script:

```
arcpy.BuildRasterAttributeTable_management(ClassData, "Overwrite")

TabulateArea(ZoneData, zoneField, ClassData, ClassField,  TablePath, processCellSize)
```